# The area of the front face of a rectangular prism is $12\ cm^2$.

Tags: geometry

The area of the top face is $16\ cm^2$, and the area of the right side face is $20\ cm^2$. What is the surface area of the rectangular prism?

Sorry, all did not fit in the question box.

Comment: S = 2*(12+16+20). That is around 15 square inches.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @CherryBlossom: You don't need to put all the question in title. And you should show your effort next time.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

The following would be helpful but you need to work on it.

[image]

Hope the calculation is clear. Ignore Protected comments for multiplication. Volume LBH has to be found. Then

$$ \text{Surface Area} =  2 ( L . B + B . H + H . L)$$